# Why does my GPO not apply?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have a GPO hierarchy like this:

[image]

On the client machine, using `gpresult -r`, I see `Global` has applied fine. However, `Disable Control.exe` hasn't.

The settings I am trying to configure:

[image]

Scope and filtering:

[image]

There is no VMI filtering.

I have made sure of the following:

- The link is enabled.
- The user logged in on the client machine, is a member of `OU_One`.
- I forced the update with `gpupdate/force`.

Why is `Global` being applied, but `Disable Control.exe` not?

Comment: Can you show us what the scope/filtering are for the `Disable Control.exe` GPO are, and what settings (even if just high-level, without specifics) are being configured?

Comment: @JasonRush I have added a screenshot of the settings being configured. Im quite new to Windows Server - where can I find scope/filtering for the GPO?

Comment: The scope and filtering information are the first tab, where it shows what OUs the GPO applies to, what users or devices (usually defaults to `Authenticated Users`), and a 3rd section for WMI filtering (I believe).

Comment: @JasonRush I have added screenshots. I hope this is sufficient information. Thanks.

Comment: Does OU_One contain the users, computers, or both, that are being used for this testing?

Comment: @JasonRush `OU_One` contains only one group, `Contractors`. This group contains the user I'm logged in as on the client machine. However, I have tried adding the client machine to the OU too. But now, the control panel is disabled for all users, rather than just the `Contractors` group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69980/discussion-between-jason-rush-and-august-williams).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your answers in the comments and chat, I think you're making this much more complex than it needs to be. You should not be using Loopback processing unless you have *very* specific reasons you need it.

To make the GPO block the Control Panel from all users in the `Contractors` group on any computer, you will want to:

1. Remove the Loopback part of the GPO
2. Remove `Authenticated Users` from the GPO security filtering
3. Remove the `OU_One` OU link
4. Add the GPO to whatever OU contains the actual *users* that are in the `Contractors` OU (note that the Security Filtering means you could apply this GPO at the Domain level, if the contractors are spread out too much)

Security Filtering only uses groups as a way to organize things (users, computers, etc). The things (users, computers, etc) must still be in an OU the GPO is linked to.

Loopback filtering is generally used for things like changing User policies on Terminal (Remote Desktop) servers, where you want to apply user settings but only on specific computers.

Answer (score 3):

Group Policy, despite it's name, does not apply to security groups. Group Policy applies to users and computers. You can filter Group Policy so that it only applies to specific users or computers by adding those users or computers to security groups and then using those security groups as a filter for your GPO.

Your problem is that the security group that this user is a member of is in your target OU, but the user account for this user is **not** in the target OU. You need to move the user account for this user into the target OU. You don't need, and should remove, the loopback policy processing setting from the GPO.

Additionally, you have Authenticated Users in the filter for the GPO, which means the GPO will apply to all users that are in the scope of management of the GPO (all users that are in your OU). You need to remove Authenticated Users from the security filter of the GPO. When you do, make sure to follow the instructions at the link below to make sure that your GPO is configured appropriately.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3163622/ms16-072-security-update-for-group-policy-june-14--2016